# Writing a Technical Paper /research paper about an assistive (technology) software project

Tags: publications, research-process, citations, thesis, research-undergraduate

I'm an undergraduate student of Computer Science. I have been working on a software project all summer, and is successfully completed now.

> The project is an assistive technology , a unique piece of software or program which runs on the Desktop/Laptop for peoples with
> disabilities.
>
> My teachers have recommended me to write a research paper on it and publish it in a international journal or a well recognized
> journal.
>
> But I don't know if a software is worth writing a paper on.? and would it be accepted in any standard journal of IT.?
>
> Do I have to include the code in the paper.? or provide a web link in the paper to the software project to be reviewed by the peers.?

Also there is some related work/papers published in some fake/bogus international journals , the papers are poorly written , the papers feels like they are written by some high school kids plus their projects are nowhere available on the Internet, the actual products that they have developed and is the topic of their research paper is no where to be found on the Internet. (ok I have to admit the authors (students) are from India).

> Now the question is that do i have to cite to these poor papers on these fake international journals.? do i have to mention them as a
> related work.? would it be considered plagiarism if i claim that there
> have never been any work done on this Topic although my project has
> additional features and different approaches and privacy related
> solutions that were not solved or mentioned in those fake journals and
> their papers.?

Those papers are not just immaturely written but the same papers has different authors in different fake journals.

I'm just worried that even if i mention those papers as related work, it might downgrade my paper as the quality of those papers is really really cheap, and if i show my work as original work which is never been done before might cost me plagiarism related issues .

Would really appreciate any research scholar to guide me.

Thank You

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. For which journals (or conferences, since this is CS) to target, ask your teacher who works in this area, as each field has their own reputable and less reputable publications (and it is also off-topic for this site).

Comment: I have explained the whole scenario with alternate questions, it is one single question in small parts.......it would be very annoying for the readers if i post these small parts as single questions and then add all the similar details of the project to everyone of them.

Comment: If the question was so dependent on the details that you absolutely have to include them all, it would not be appropriate for SE. But the question "Do I have to cite dubious papers from predatory journals?" seems like a perfectly good question without further context.

Comment: Journals could be IEEE, academia, ACM human computer interaction, Springer, or other open access journals of Computer Science.

Comment: @shinwari_afg nengel is right, the second block of questions is unrelated to the first one. Please make it two separate questions.